# Decompiling Non PC Binary

Tags: gdb, decompiling, disassembly, bin

I have a binary file for some old music hardware I own that's been out of production for the past 3 years. The company is now bust and no longer exists.

I'm trying to reverse engineer the binary file.

I've tried opening in a hex editor, I can see some ASCII text, but there are lots of symbols and characters in there that make no sense. Does this mean its encrypted?

I've tried to disassemble using gdb but I always get "No symbol table is loaded.  Use the "file" command.". If I use the string command at the terminal I can see a lot of strings that are using the software. Again, there is also lots of strings that are not human readable.

Can anyone push me in the right direction so that I can get some workable assembly code for this?

Comment: No offense, but if "symbols that make no sense" is the first thing that comes to your mind when you open a file in a hex editor, I think you might want to start a little lower and take things slow. How about disassembling a binary on your home platform that you've compiled yourself as a warm-up?

Comment: "A binary file" -- you mean like a jpeg? That has strings in it too. Seriously just because it's binary doesn't mean it's executable. And even if it is, odds are even if you *can* get an assembly representation, it *still* won't make sense. Sorry to be a downer. If you *do* reverse engineer it though super kudos to you, you're better than me.

Comment: No it's not a jpeg. It's the software for the hardware. I've done assembly at university, and decompiled stuff I write myself. I have lots of time, just learning really with the help of Google.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need some HW knowledge of what CPU/Environment for this binary is used, [IDA Pro](http://www.hex-rays.com/idapro/) tool and lots of patience.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try find the hardware specs on the device.

Comment: Thanks again Sergey, IDA on OSX works perfectly. I'm able to make more sense of this. I tried for find IDA earlier today but was being redirected to some page saying its no longer available. Thanks again.